# Rancher - AWS, RKE gives default backend - 404 error

Tags: rancher

All,

We installed Kubernetes with RKE in our AWS environment  as per the link - https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/ha/

All the steps worked mostly fine and the nodes are healthy in the AWS NLB. I do not see any issue with any pods. But when we hit the NLB url --> https://nlburl.amazonaws.com it gives an error/message as "default backend - 404". Same error comes up when I type within each of the nodes when i type localhost. Version and other cmd outputs shown below.

Thoughts or inputs on how to debug and fix the issue?

```
ubuntu@xxx:/tmp$ ./rke -v
rke version v0.1.14

ubuntu@xxx:/tmp$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.1", GitCommit:"eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-13T10:39:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

ubuntu@xxx:/tmp$ kubectl --kubeconfig /tmp/kube_config_cluster.yml get ingress -n cattle-system -o wide
NAME      HOSTS                     ADDRESS                                    PORTS     AGE
rancher   rancher.mydomain.com   1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8,9.0.1.2   80, 443   19h

ubuntu@xxx:/tmp$ kubectl --kubeconfig /tmp/kube_config_cluster.yml get nodes
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                      AGE   VERSION
1.2.3.4   Ready    controlplane,etcd,worker   21h   v1.11.5
5.6.7.8   Ready    controlplane,etcd,worker   21h   v1.11.5
9.0.1.2   Ready    controlplane,etcd,worker   21h   v1.11.5


ubuntu@xxx:/tmp$ kubectl --kubeconfig /tmp/kube_config_cluster.yml describe ingress -n cattle-system
Name:             rancher
Namespace:        cattle-system
Address:          1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8,9.0.1.2
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  tls-rancher-ingress terminates rancher.mydomain.com
Rules:
  Host                     Path  Backends
  ----                     ----  --------
  rancher.mydomain.com
                              rancher:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  certmanager.k8s.io/issuer:                          rancher
  field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:                    [{"addresses":["1.2.3.4","5.6.7.8","9.0.1.2"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"cattle-system:rancher","ingressName":"cattle-system:rancher","hostname":"rancher.mydomain.com","allNodes":false}]
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout:  30
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout:     1800
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout:     1800
Events:                                               <none>

ubuntu@1.2.3.4:/tmp$ curl localhost
default backend - 404
```

Answer (score 1):

The 404 you are seeing is from the default backed of the cluster ingress.

You are accessing the Rancher Server URL incorrectly. Try https://rancher.mydomain.com

For it to work, either need to have a DNS entry pointing `rancher.mydomain.com` to the NLB's CNAME or have a similar entry in `/etc/hosts` on your local machine.